# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1-e^{ax})(1-e^{bx})}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1-e^{ax})(1-e^{bx})}dx$$ for constants $a,b$.

I tried separation by partial fractions, but couldn't do it.

Comment: @T.Bongers, the signs are different.

Comment: @dfeuer The solution procedure is still pretty much identical, since $$\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{1 - y} = \frac{x - y}{(1 - x)(1 - y)}$$

Comment: @T.Bongers, that's valid, but it's still not actually an exact duplicate.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, you're right that they aren't the exact same question.